# Convert ActiveRecord::Relation into a usable array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, activerecord

When I call:

```
preivous_lessons = @item.where("track_id = ?", lesson.track_id)
```

I get this active record realtion:

`[#<CodeLesson id: 2, name: "Python", permalink: "python", lesson_content: "", instructions: "Print your name to the console.", hints: "", starting_code: "\"\"\"\r\nThis is a comment\r\n\"\"\"\r\n\r\nprint(\"Hello, World\"...", language_id: "12", order: 1, track_id: 2, user_id: 1, created_at: "2014-02-14 16:01:12", updated_at: "2014-02-15 21:14:43", visible: true>, #<CodeLesson id: 8, name: "Test Lesson", permalink: "test-lesson", lesson_content: nil, instructions: nil, hints: nil, starting_code: nil, language_id: "26", order: nil, track_id: 2, user_id: 1, created_at: "2014-02-20 19:23:15", updated_at: "2014-02-20 19:23:15", visible: false>]`

How do I convert this into a usable array of models so I can do something like this:

```
preivous_lessons.each do |i|
  highest = i.order if i.order > highest
end
```

Comment: do as `highest = preivous_lessons.map(&:order).max`

Comment: or `highest = preivous_lessons.maximum(:order)`

Comment: @ArupRakshit Then I get this error `comparison of NilClass with 1 failed`

Comment: Did you try `@item.where("track_id = ?", lesson.track_id).maximum(:order)`?

Comment: Got it working, the error was an unrelated issue. @ArupRakshit post and answer and I will select it as the top answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As OP confirmed from my [*comment*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21920844/convert-activerecordrelation-into-a-usable-array?noredirect=1#comment33202732_21920844), that my hint solved his problem, I am putting it as an answer to the post :

```
preivous_lessons = @item.where("track_id = ?", lesson.track_id)
highest = preivous_lessons.maximum(:order)
```

Documentation of [`maximum`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-maximum) :

> Calculates the **maximum** value on a given column. The value is returned with the same data type of the column, or `nil` if there's no row.

Answer (score 0):

```
preivous_lessons = @item.where("track_id = ?", lesson.track_id).all
```